# Heroku And Salesforce Connectivity

Tags: salesforce-id, java, heroku, heroku-connect

I have created Connectivity with Salesforce using "Heroku Connect". While i create record in salesforce it is creating record in heroku postgres database but while i inserted record in to heroku postgres databse using cmd it inserted in the postgres database but its not reflected in salesforce same time it is not showing proper record count in "Heroku Connect--> mapping".

Comment: Heroku connect is not real-time sync. Sometimes it takes some time to generate the sfId and get everything in sync.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I got the solution to this.